# Custom color in a map(polygons) by ggplot in R and plot a legend

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a certain map(polygons) with personalized colors and its respective legend - it is a colum in my data. I don't know how to determine this colors and labels in my code. When I plot the map,  the colors are others.

My real data has hounders of sectors to be ploted, but for explain you, I will show only  the first six lines and the colors and legend's labels

```
unique(data$color)
[1] green  yellow red    orange blue  
Levels: blue green orange red yellow

unique(data$legend)
[1] aa1  aa2 aa3 aa4 aa5 
Levels: aa1  aa2 aa3 aa4 aa5 

head(data)

            id  color legend
1 3.300456e+14  green    aa2
2 3.300456e+14 yellow    aa4
3 3.300456e+14    red    aa5
4 3.300456e+14 orange    aa3
5 3.300456e+14  green    aa2
6 3.300456e+14 orange    aa3
```

First situation: legend ok, but with other colors

```
ggplot() +

geom_map(data=data, aes(map_id=id, fill = color), map=map.fort)+

geom_path(data=map.fort, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), colour="black", size=0.25)
```

[image]

Second situation: Colors ok, but legend is not ploted

```
geom_map(data=data, aes(map_id=id),fill = data$color, map=map.fort)+

geom_path(data=map.fort, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), colour="black", size=0.25)
```

[image]

All that I want is plot my map like the first image, but with my color personalized and the respective legend label

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the `fill` aesthetic to `as.character(color)` and then adding

```
scale_fill_identity(guide = "legend")
```

after the geom's.

Untested, since example unreproducible.

---

Answering the modified question:

Putting both the color and the legend in the data frame is not necessary; ggplot handles it differently. Set the `fill` aesthetic to `legend` and add

```
scale_fill_manual(values=(aa2="green", aa3="orange", aa4="yellow", aa5="red"))
```

This is probably now a duplicate, though.

Comment: Brian, I added the map. Your suggestion really works. But I have other questions. I don't know the function of the word "legend" in the code,since the legend's title is not "legend". I would like change the labels on the legend, for example: instead "blue", I want put "Very good" ; instead "green", "Goog"; instead "orange", "Neither good, neither bad"; etc..

Comment: Also, I would like to plot the legend in order: First, the blue box, green box under the blue box, the orange box under the green box, etc.

Comment: Brian, I redid my question